# v8 FunctionTemplate::GetFunction() crashes with Access Violation

Tags: c++, v8, embedded-v8

I have a really simple method that initializes v8, I am unable to track the reason (other v8 stuff works just fine):

```
void JavascriptEngine::init() {
    m_platform = v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform();

    v8::V8::InitializeExternalStartupData(".");

    v8::V8::InitializeICU();
    v8::V8::InitializePlatform(&*m_platform);
    v8::V8::Initialize();

    v8::Isolate::CreateParams create_params;
    create_params.array_buffer_allocator = 
        v8::ArrayBuffer::Allocator::NewDefaultAllocator();
    m_isolate = v8::Isolate::New(create_params);

    v8::Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(m_isolate);
    v8::HandleScope handle_scope(m_isolate);

    m_context = make_unique<v8::Persistent<v8::Context>>(m_isolate, 
        create_new_context());

    v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate> t = v8::FunctionTemplate::New(m_isolate);
    t->SetClassName(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(m_isolate, "Test", v8::NewStringType::kNormal).ToLocalChecked());
    t->Set(m_isolate, "func_property", v8::Number::New(m_isolate, 1));

    auto f = t->GetFunction(); // CRASH

    ...//rest of the code
}
```

Error I got:

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
**this** was nullptr.
```

Using Visual Studio 2017. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

To `GetFunction` you need to have `Context` and enter it. Depends on what v8 version you use, there are methods which require `Isolate` and `Context` be passed explicitly. In general, this is what v8 internally moves to - to pass `Isolate` and `Context` to methods that require that (there couldb some inconsistency, though).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was a good clue to fix my problem. ;)